# my delete query won't delete anything from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website .. and in this page, I want to show all data in mysql and select one row and delete it all from the mysql, but when I do testing (row_affect) it gives nothing has changed.. it shows all info from my database, and everything ok, but when I want to delete, it won't delete.
this is the code..

```
<?php

//Connect to DB
//include_once("Project/CIEconn.php");
$mysqlCON= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","CIE") or die(mysqli_connect_error()); 
mysqli_select_db($mysqlCON,'CIE') or die ("no database");



$IDID = isset($_POST['Id']); // 1 2 

if( isset($_POST['delete']) ){
        if( empty($IDID) || $IDID == 0 ){
            echo"<h4>  please choose something to delete   </h4>";
        }else{


            echo $IDID ; 
            echo "<br>" ;

            $impid = implode(" , " ,  $_POST['Id']);



$sqlDelete = ("DELETE  FROM Shopping WHERE Id IN ('".$impid."') ") ;
$DeleteQuery = mysqli_query($mysqlCON,$sqlDelete) or die ("Error : ".mysqli_error($mysqlCON));

// TEST ONLY ////////----------------------------------------////////////
if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqlCON) > 0) {
    echo "You have successfully updated your data.<br><br>";
}
else {
    echo "The data you submitted matched the current data so nothing was changed.<br><br>";
}
if (!$DeleteQuery) {
    die("Invalid query:" );
}


//var_dump($DeleteQuery );
////////----------------------------------------////////////

                     if(isset($DeleteQuery )){
                        echo"<h3> Done Deleting .... !!</h3>";

                    }else {echo "Error While Deleting...";}
        }


 }



$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM Shopping  ";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqlCON,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($mysqlCON)); 


echo '
<form action= "Shop_Sup.php"  method = "post">
<table width ="100%" cellpadding ="4" border="1" >

<tr>
<th>Check </th>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Jobs Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th> No Students needed</th>
<th>Due Date</th>
</tr>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){

// name = 'Id[]'
    echo "<tr>

<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Id[]'  vlaue='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>


 <td>". $row['Id'] ." </td>
 <td> ". $row['JobName'] ." </td>
 <td> ". $row['Description'] ." </td>
 <td> ". $row['NoStudent'] . "</td>
<td>". $row['Date'] ." </td>
</tr>";


}

echo '
</table>
<br/>

<div align="center">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />

<input type="reset" value="Clear Marks" />
</div>

</form>

';

?>

<html>
<head><title> Shopping.. </title></head>
<br>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get any error on screen?

Comment: after adjusting my delete query to this.."DELETE FROM Shopping WHERE Id IN (" . $impid . ")";
this is what I get ......
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on)' at line 1

Comment: what does `echo $IDID ;` output?

Comment: echo $IDID just for testing..

Comment: The answer had already been given now. But I wanted to see what you were sending as that was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of the incorrect single quotes in `DELETE` query,

```
$sqlDelete = ("DELETE  FROM Shopping WHERE Id IN ('".$impid."') ") ;
                                                  ^          ^
```

So your `DELETE` query should be like this:

```
$sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM Shopping WHERE Id IN (" . $impid . ")";
```

**Edited:**

If `$_POST['Id']` contains array of strings, then do this:

```
// your code

$impid = implode("' , '" ,  $_POST['Id']);
$sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM Shopping WHERE Id IN ('" . $impid . "')";

// now execute $sqlDelete query
```

Also there's a problem in your HTML code. Look at this statement here,

```
<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Id[]'  vlaue='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>
                                           ^ here
```

It should be,

```
<td> <input type='checkbox' name='Id[]' value='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>
```

Comment: thank you Sir, but I changed it to the one u recommended , and it gave me an error in the query and it died..

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on)' at line 1

Comment: @ssSsSs The query looks good to me. Did you get the syntax error in this query or some other query?

Comment: the error occur in the DeleteQuerry. the code die and shows this error 

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on)' at line 1

by the way, after implode the selceted items, it shows as "on" 
if i picked like 3 it shows like "on""on" "on"

Comment: @ssSsSs Do `echo $sqlDelete;` and tell me what it's displaying.

Comment: I did echo $sqlDelete before the query and that what i got.
DELETE FROM Shopping WHERE Id IN (on , on)

I selected two rows..

Comment: @ssSsSs Oh, so your `Id` column contains strings. I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: thank you for ur eidt. now it shows no error, but it won't delete, and when i run the ( mysqli_affected_rows($mysqlCON) >0 ) to test  it result to nothing happend to the DB, when i echo the $sqlDelete I go thos  (DELETE FROM Shopping WHERE Id IN ('on' , 'on')  )

Comment: @ssSsSs Did you change the HTML code like I suggested? Perhaps there's no `Id` named `on` in that column. Check again.

Comment: @ssSsSs Happy to hear. Please mark the answer as *accepted* if it resolved your issue. :) [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)